# How to accept HMR on option API vue 3 + Pinia

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite, pinia

I had some trouble with use pinia and vue 3(opt). In my case i can't understand how to accept hmr on pinia storages.

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export default defineStore('user', {
    state: () => ({
        authState: false,
   }))
```

defining store view like this, it not a function that i can void later in

```
import.meta.hot.accept(storeName, import.meta.hot)
```

and now im stooped with it and can't understand how to accept using Vite hmr with my storages

Already try to use `import.meta.hot.accept(storeName, import.meta.hot)` in my main component Application.vue but it return false with thow about unknown modules

Anybody know how to use HMR stores with Option API of VUE 3?

Comment: in docs of pinia used composition api and define store look like this ``` export const = defineStore()```  in my case it look like a ```export default defineStore()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my mistake was that i don't use a named export/import in my pinia stores.

right way be
somestore.js

```
import { defineStore, acceptHMRUpdate } from "pinia";

export const somestore = defineStore('uniqueId',{
   state:()=>({}),
   getters:{},
   actions:{}
})

if (import.meta.hot) {
    import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(somestore, import.meta.hot))
}
```

and then in components need to named import of store { somestore }

```
import { mapStores } from 'pinia';
import { somestore } from './somestore.js'

export default{
   computed:{
   ...mapStores(somestore)
   }
}
```

this example of code wrote with OPTIONS API of vuejs

Thnx f attention